# Read api calls of app with Appium

Tags: java, api, testing, mobile, appium

we are experimenting with Appium for our mobile testing. I couldn't find how to read the API calls our app does towards our backend. Is it possible to 'listen' to the network calls of the app and for example read the JSON body that is returned from our backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways of recording the network calls:

1) Set up proxy in your mobile via any of the proxy tool you use like charles, wireshark. What I mean is manually open whatever GUI tool you have and route your traffic via the tool as when you want to listen to network traffic.

2) Another way is through browsermob proxy. This would generate a HAR file of all the network calls that were made(would give the headers of the response and not JSON data).Maven Dependency is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-core-littleproxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-beta-3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add this where you create your environment:

```
// Starting server BrowserMobProxy

    server= new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    server.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    server.start(8897);
    Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(server);
```

Set capabilities:

```
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
```

After the driver is set up, create a HAR file

```
 server.newHar("2.har");
```

In your @AfterSuite add below:

```
 if(server.getHar()==null){
        System.out.println("No Har capture");
    }
    Har har = server.getHar();
    if(har==null){
        System.out.println("Har is NULL");
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_OUTPUT_HAR+"fos"+".har");
    har.writeTo(fos);



    HarLog log = har.getLog();
    if(log==null){
        System.out.println("Harlog is null");
    }
    List<HarEntry> entries = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HarEntry>(log.getEntries());
            System.out.println("entries"+entries);
            for (HarEntry entry : entries){
                System.out.println("entry="+entry.getRequest().getUrl());
            }

    File harFile = new File(HAR_FILE_PATH+"2"+".har");
    File("/Users/yourpath/"+"2"+".har");        
    har.writeTo(harFile);
```

Comment: Thanks Tabish. Does this work in with Appium server as well? I noticed appium is not supported by BrowserMobProxy. Here is the link  https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4968. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I tried the apporach as well you mentioned, har file is generated without any information more than the basics. Here is the info. {
 "log": {
  "version": "1.2",
  "creator": {
   "name": "BrowserMob Proxy",
   "version": "2.1.0-beta-3-littleproxy",
   "comment": ""
  },
  "pages": [{
   "id": "Second.har",
   "startedDateTime": "2016-05-26T21:42:46.453+02:00",
   "title": "Second.har",
   "pageTimings": {
    "comment": ""
   },
   "comment": ""
  }],
  "entries": [],
  "comment": ""
 }
}

Comment: Did you set up your phone to route its traffic via proxy port(8897 in the example)?

Comment: Yes Tried it that but app starts complaining that the network is being monitored. Also my app does not work on Rooted devices.

Comment: Any idea how can make my device listen to BrowserMobProxy server?

Comment: Unless you configure proxy in your device, BrowserMobProxy wont be able to listen and your harfile will be empty.I suggest, If your logcat logs network calls then you can set appropriate filter to listen to them. Dig around, you will easily find the implementation. Do tell me if you face problems.

Comment: @vm31 did you manage to capture traffic with browsermob ? can you please share code ?